# How to get [Authorize] attribute work in .NET Core 6 Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, authorize-attribute

I am a noob, trying to do **JWT** the **simplest** possible way on a .NET Core 6 Web API project, but I can't even get it to work.

Requirement: You need to be logged in to call the `GetProductList` API.
(I am testing this on Swagger that comes with the project)

FYI, my **Login controller**: (working as intended)

```
    [HttpPost("login")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginDto request)
    {
        var user = GetUserFromRequest(request);

        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest("Invalid credentials.");

        string jwt = CreateJwtToken(user.Id.ToString());
        Response.Cookies.Append(COOKIE_JWT, jwt, _cookieOptions);

        return Ok();
    }

    [HttpGet("user")]
    public IActionResult GetUser() 
    {
        try
        {
            var jwt = Request.Cookies[COOKIE_JWT];
            var userId = VerifyJwtAndGetUserId(jwt);

            return Ok(GetUserById(userId));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            return Unauthorized();
        }
    }

    public static string CreateJwtToken(string userId)
    {
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JWT_KEY));
        var cred = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: userId,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(365),
            signingCredentials: cred
        );
        var jwt = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        return jwt;
    }

    public static string VerifyJwtAndGetUserId(string jwt)
    {
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        tokenHandler.ValidateToken(jwt, new TokenValidationParameters {
            IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JWT_KEY)),
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidateAudience = false
        }, out SecurityToken validatedToken);

        string userId = validatedToken.Issuer;
        return userId;
    }
```

The question is, **how can I make the `[Authorize]` attribute work?**

```
    [HttpGet("list")]
    //[Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult<List<Product>>> GetProductList()
    {
        return Ok(GetProducts());
    }
```

The above works, but adding `[Authorize]` attribute gives a **401** with the following header: (while GetUser above is fine)

```
 content-length: 0 
 date: Mon,13 Jun 2022 23:27:32 GMT 
 server: Kestrel 
 www-authenticate: Bearer
```

This is what's in my **Program.cs**: (maybe this is wrong?)

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddJwtBearer(options => {
    options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters {  // similar to the one in controller
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JWT_KEY)),
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false
    };
    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents {  // https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/07/25/net-core-jwt-cookie-authentication/
        OnMessageReceived = ctx => {
            ctx.Token = ctx.Request.Cookies["jwt"];
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    };
  });
```

**SOLUTION:**

Move `app.UseAuthentication();` above `app.UserAuthorization();`.

Comment: your endpoint is expecting a bearer token, your request needs an Authorization Bearer HTTP Header adding to it

Comment: `issuer: userId` <-- This is very incorrect. You're mixing up the `sub` (subject) claim with the `issuer` claim.

Comment: Thanks fuzzybear and Dai. Is there any way to quick fix this just to get it working? I'm a noob with JWT a sample code would really help

Comment: Have you tried https://spin.atomicobject.com/2020/07/25/net-core-jwt-cookie-authentication/ ?

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Thx! It seemed like what I need but it still doesn't work (same 401 error in Swagger)

Comment: So your actual question is about swagger-ui? https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/cookie-authentication/ / `services.AddSwaggerGen(c => c.AddSecurityDefinition("Name", new OpenApiSecurityScheme { In = ParameterLocation.Cookie, ... }));`

Comment: No of course not, eventually it needs to work on a frontend. I am just trying to get Authorize attribute to work, trying to do it the simplest way

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

#### FrontEnd

According to [JWT Introduction](https://jwt.io/introduction) as below

> Whenever the user wants to access a protected route or resource, the
> user agent should send the JWT, typically in the Authorization header
> using the Bearer schema. The content of the header should look like
> the following:
>
> Authorization: Bearer [token]

So you need to add a header `Authorization: Bearer <token>` in your request on frontEnd. 
a simple example at frontEnd. In this example the `yourApiUrl` should be your `list` api route.

```js
   const token = getCookieValue(`COOKIE_JWT`);
   fetch(yourApiUrl, {
            headers: {
              "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`,
            }
          })
```

getCookieValue function

```js
const getCookieValue(name) =>{
document.cookie.match('(^|;)\\s*' + name + '\\s*=\\s*([^;]+)')?.pop() || ''
}
```

then your request will have the authorization header with a prefix [**Bearer**].
a picture from my browser's dev tool.
[image]

and then the `[Authorize]` attribute should work

---

#### BackEnd

Maybe it is not the problem at frontEnd, then you can check the backEnd's code.
Some code example at backEnd `.NET 6 WebApi` about generate or examine the JWT token

**GenerateToken function**
Use to generate token when sign-in controller

```
  public string GenerateToken(TokenModel tokenModel, int 
    expireMinutes = 30)
    {
        var issuer = this._configuration.GetValue<string> ("JwtSettings:Issuer");
        var signKey = this._configuration.GetValue<string> 
("JwtSettings:SignKey");

        // Configuring "Claims" to your JWT Token
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Iss, issuer),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()), // JWT ID
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, tokenModel.EmployeeNo), // User.Identity.Name
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.NameId, tokenModel.EmployeeNo),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Name, tokenModel.EmployeeName),
        };

        for (int i = 0; i < tokenModel.Roles.Length; i++)
        {
            claims.Add(new Claim("roles", tokenModel.Roles[i]));
        }

        var userClaimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

        // Create a SymmetricSecurityKey for JWT Token signatures
        var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signKey));

        // HmacSha256 MUST be larger than 128 bits, so the key can't be too short. At least 16 and more characters.
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);

        // Create SecurityTokenDescriptor
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = userClaimsIdentity,
            NotBefore = DateTime.Now, // Default is DateTime.Now
            IssuedAt = DateTime.Now, // Default is DateTime.Now
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(expireMinutes),
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
        };

        // Generate a JWT securityToken, than get the serialized Token result (string)
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var serializeToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);

        return serializeToken;
    }
```

**Program.cs**
`.NET6 WebApi`'s setting in `Program.cs` about examine Jwt token.
 **[NOTICE]:** the method `builder.Services.AddAuthorization();` **MUST** below the `builder.Services.AddAuthentication` method, or
will result error.

```
   builder.Services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) //check the HTTP Header's Authorization has the JWT Bearer Token
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",

                RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role",

                // varify Issuer
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:Issuer"),

                //  Important!!! audience need to be set to false
                // Because the default is true. 
                // So if you didn't set this prop when generate token, then the api will always return a check token error
                ValidateAudience = false,

                ValidateLifetime = true,

                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey =
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(
                    Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:SignKey")))
            };
        });

    builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
```

---

#### Easy Test by thunder client of VsCode

1. Use [the thumder client VsCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client) to test the api route.
2. Use the swagger's login controller to get the JWTToken.
3. Then paste the token in thunder client, and add the prefix `Bearer`

   a simple image of thunder client
   [image]

Comment: Thanks HsuTingHuan!! Does that mean I cannot test it using Swagger? I'll try creating a frontend for it...

Comment: unfortunately you can not test it by swagger I thought
I usually use the thumder client of vscode   
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rangav.vscode-thunder-client

Comment: Hi @HsuTingHuan, thanks a lot for helping! I haven't tried Thunder, but I tried using Postman but still getting a 401. I tried your code but replacing `fetch` with `axios.get` and still getting 401 too. We've got the cookie, is there any way to tell .NET to look at the cookie instead of having to copy it to Request Header?

Comment: I think the custom attribute can do this work..
Have you change `issuer` to `sub`?

Comment: Stop using bearer authentication for websites, really. Use cookie authentication with Identity. Yes you will need 2 controllers (web+api for mobile) but since your controllers don't contain any logic, it's no big deal. Then simply add XSRF protection to your web controllers, and you're done. [Example here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer/tree/master/MintPlayer.Web)

Comment: @HsuTingHuan I moved `app.UseAuthentication()` up and it worked! So silly lol. Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I have changed Issuer with Claim NameId thanks to your sample code!